# Visual Studio 2010: "Source Control - Unable To Access Database"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clearcase

Our team uses ClearCase here at work, and I absolutely despise the ClearCase Visual Studio plug-in.  It is such an unnatural workflow for me.  As a result, I uninstalled the ClearCase plug-in and simply use the cleartool command line utility, which has increased my productivity significantly.

However, I am now presented with a new annoyance.  All our project files are configured to use Visual Studio Source Control hooks, and so when I first open the project, I get a super annoying error message:

```
Source Control - Unable To Access Database

The associated source control plug-in is not installed or could not be initialized.
Common causes for this error include server unavailability and/or incorrect workspace mappings.

O Temporarily work uncontrolled
o Permanentnly remove source control association bindings
```

Neither of the options given are what I really want to do, since the default temporarily solution bugs me every time I open a project, and the "permanent" solution hijacks my solution file.

Alternatively, I have gone to Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug-in selection -> None.  This still results in a Visual Studio message, albeit a slightly less annoying one.

What are my options?  Is it possible to write a plug-in for Visual Studio that completely turns off this nuissance?  I mean, could I write a Source Control plug-in that *does nothing?*

Comment: Is it possible it is a schema issue? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21122462 (or http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21148890). If not, our IT support tells me they usually uninstall Visual Studio, and reinstall it, to make sure there is no trace of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is Visual Studio was installed after ClearCase installation. I have faced similar issue and the only option is to un-install ClearCase and reinstall  it.

Comment: I can no longer verify since I got tired of working for a company that used ClearCase for source control, and now work for a real software company.